# Crt unit for Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, crt

I need Crt unit for Delphi 2010 console application (ReadKey, GotoXY, ...). Is there any Crt unit for Delphi 2010?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd start with any of the CRT units [here](http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=236).

Comment: +1. Because when you are looking for ready to use code, look at torry.net.

Comment: Thanks, none for Delphi 2010 :) but I will try.

Comment: If anyone will need too - http://www.delphi-zone.com/2010/09/how-to-use-a-crt-unit-for-delphi/. Works fine with some modifications (Char / AnsiChar, ...).

Comment: I made it work on Unicode Delphi (see next answer) and posted the files on my skydrive, so anybody can see them. (Some people might not be able to do the conversion that you did, Branko.)

Answer (score 1):

I updated the code from Branko's link, and came up with this:

https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=F5BB35AE00415BC7&resid=F5BB35AE00415BC7%21232&authkey=AIKZAtMjhUyE-TQ

It's a working Crt32 for unicode delphi.  Changes required include char->AnsiChar, pChar->PAnsiChar, and VariousWin32ApiFunction() to VariousWin32ApiFunctionA().

Comment: Do you know when it would be useful to set {$Define OneByOne} ?

Comment: Your off site link is duff