# Converting from pascal to Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I am converting a Pascal program to Delphi using CRT32. There is one command, mem, that is not recognized in Delphi. I use it to save screen memory on a stack in order to save all or part of a window so that I can restore it after deleting a window that was put on top of the original window. Any ideas?

BTW, I have added a new procedure to CRT32 to supplement ReadKey because the ReadKey function does not read function keys.  I can share if anybody is interested.

Comment: "from pascal" There are tons of different "pascal" languages - which one? Delphi itself is Pascal.

Comment: @Jerry: Delphi is not Pascal, although it may have its origins there. The official language name is Delphi, and there are many, many aspects of the Delphi language that are not found in Pascal (generics, for instance, or anonymous methods or class helpers). Delphi is to Pascal what C++ is to C - while they may have started at the same place, they are nowhere near the same language.

Comment: @KenWhite Pascal syntax I meant, but yes indeed still not technically the same. My point was "pascal" is vague - we need to know the exact language/framework. Erik, We can't help with code that we cannot see.

Comment: @Jerry: I agree we need to know what Pascal code is being ported to Delphi. My disagreement is with your *Delphi itself is Pascal*, which is inaccurate.

Comment: There are lots of Crt units for Delphi around, see [Crt unit for Delphi 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4706603/576719) and [Crt32](http://www.zieglersoft.dk/public/crt32.asp?temp=982&language=uk).

Comment: Yes, we don't know what this CRT32 is, and what this `mem` is. Some extra details are needed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, `mem[absoluteaddress]` is from Turbo Pascal, accessing memory function.

Comment: I'm not sure there's much point in arguing about what Pascal is. I think it's fair to say that the Delphi language is a direct Pascal derivative, or in the Pascal family, which is what Jerry meant, as I read it. If the original code is Turbo Pascal, then that's not official ISO Pascal either.

Comment: @Erik Have a read of this http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/prog/progse36.html  What it tells you is that you likely need to understand what the code was doing, why it used `mem`, and then come up with a way to solve the problem in a different way. Suited to the tool at hand. If you want any help from us I think you'd need to supply more details.

Comment: @David: Thanks for you feedback. C++ is a direct C derivative, but they're hardly the same. C# is a direct derivative of both Delphi and C, thanks to Anders, but again they're hardly the same. We don't know what the original code is, because the poster didn't say, so we don't know whether it's ISO Pascal or not. I'd think you, as the most inflexible enforcer of technical accuracy I've ever encountered here, who quibbles emphatically over minor phrasing interpretations, would have little reason to object to being accurate. Delphi is not Pascal, and I pointed out the roots in my first remark.

Comment: @Ken Please don't be personal

Comment: FWIW I think that @Jerry made a good point. Pascal is too generic. If it can be used to describe TP, then so it can to describe Delphi. In other words we need more detail. Everyone is agreed on that.

Comment: @David: There was nothing personal. It's a statement of fact, which I can provide sufficient links to support. You've stated many times here that *this is a technical site, and therefore accuracy is important* and used that as the rationale to debate minor phrasing and word choices. Why is it only important to be accurate sometimes (where you're free to point it out) and not at other times (where you're not the one to mention it)? I've also already agreed that Jerry made a good point about "Pascal" being too generic. TP *was* Pascal  (thus the use of Pascal in its name).

Comment: @Ken So, we agree then. Good.

Comment: @Ken The official language name of Delphi is Object Pascal nowadays. They changed it with the introduction of Appmethod.

Comment: @iamjoosy: The XE7 documentation refers to it as the Delphi language (it includes the *Delphi Language Guide*  in the *Delphi Reference* heading under *RAD Studio Topics*).

Comment: @Ken They'll probably update the documentation in time for the release of XE17.

Answer (score 1):

`mem` is a function in Turbo Pascal for accessing 16 bit DOS memory. In your case it is used for direct access of the console text part in the memory located at a certain address.

Since this is not possible (does not exist) in windows, there has to be a function in your library that records everyting written onto the the console, for later retrieval, or using ways to access the windows console by other means.

You might get some inspiration from this library, [Crt replacement for Delphi (fully functional) 1.20](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/19810).

Comment: Can't he just use a crt unit ported to Delphi? Don't they offer reading services?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, yes many Crt units ported to Delphi can read write to the windows console, I updated the answer. I implemented a full emulated console GUI component with graph support once.

Comment: @Erik - Could you clear up for certain please - which Pascal are you converting FROM and to which version of Delphi do you wish to convert?  I bet you will get a working answer in no time from some of these chaps if you answer that.

Comment: Well, technically `Mem` was neither function, nor command, but a variable with absolute address. I also suspect it was magical, because of non-ordinal index.