Turbo explorer Delphi KeyPressed and ReadKey replacement
Just tried to receive some information about the keyboard when I noticed CRT is not delivered with Turbo Delphi Explorer... It is shipped under conio.h with Turbo C++ Explorer, but not with Delphi version...
I tried to google for that and found some crt.pas unit, that just doesn't compile with this Explorer version of Delphi...
Disappointed, I google more and found (on stackoverflow too) co-pilot giving me some code (called functional), to get a keypressed or a key read from console... I inserted the code into my program, but it hangs...
Here is the code that compile run and hangs...
function KeyPressed : Boolean;


         var _buffer : TInputRecord;
             _read   : DWORD;

         begin
              Result := false;

              if Windows.PeekConsoleInput(STD_INPUT_HANDLE, _buffer, 1, _read)
                 then if _read > 0
                         then if _buffer.EventType = KEY_EVENT
                                 then if _buffer.Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown
                                         then begin
                                                   Windows.FlushConsoleInputBuffer(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

                                                   Result := true;
                                              end;
         end;

function KeyRead : Char;

         var _buffer : TInputRecord;
             _read   : DWORD;

         begin
              Result := #0;

              repeat
                    if Windows.ReadConsoleInput(STD_INPUT_HANDLE, _buffer, 1, _read)
                       then if _read > 0
                               then if _buffer.EventType = KEY_EVENT
                                       then if _buffer.Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown
                                               then Result := _buffer.Event.KeyEvent.AsciiChar;
              until Result <> #0;
         end;

Any one could point me to a right direction ?
PS :
On start of this program I put the 2 following lines (required)
Windows.GetConsoleMode(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, _save);
Windows.SetConsoleMode(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, _save or ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT or $0080);

Hangs where exactly? Please be more specific. Where are these functions being used in your code? What are you trying to accomplish in the first place that you needed the old CRT functionality to begin with? And why are you still using an outdated Delphi product that was discontinued almost 20 years ago?

a simple program :while KeyPressed = false do Sleep(0); will hang.... I just want to use KeyPress and ReadKey from that old CRT unit... Looks like if ReadConsoleInput always return false...

I suceeded to write a KeyPress using GetAsynkKeyState and I am working on ReadKey....

"a simple program :while KeyPressed = false do Sleep(0); will hang" - Have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger? Or do any kind of logging? As soon as any non-keyboard or non-keydown event reaches the front of the input buffer, your loop will get stuck indefinitely peeking the same event over and over since you are not processing it or discarding it

No ... I found what I wanted and posted it as answer... That doesnt answer my or your questions, but solves my requirements...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706603/crt-unit-for-delphi-2010 this page holds what I need...
